# How to connect to a RabbitMQ cluster with a Python Client using pika?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, cluster-computing, pika

I have a Python client that uses Pika package (0.9.13) and retrieves data from one node in a RabbitMQ cluster. The cluster is composed of two nodes placed in two different host (url_1 and url_2). How can I make my Python client to subscribe to both nodes?

That is the main structure of my code:

```
import pika
credentials = pika.PlainCredentials(user, password)
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host=url_1,
                                     credentials=credentials, ssl=ssl, port=port))
channel = connection.channel() 
channel.exchange_declare(exchange=exchange.name, 
                         type=exchange.type, durable=exchange.durable)

result = channel.queue_declare(queue=queue.name, exclusive=queue.exclusive, 
                             durable=queue.durable, auto_delete=queue.autoDelete)
channel.queue_bind(exchange=exchange.name, queue=queue.name, 
                   routing_key=binding_key)
channel.basic_consume(callback,
                  queue=queue.name,
                  no_ack=True)

channel.start_consuming()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a cluster it is not important in which node you are connected.

Usually in to solve this typical problem it is enough to configure a simple load-balancer and connect the clients to the L.B.

> clients-----> LB ------> rabbitmq(s) instances cluster.

**EDIT:**

Load balancer as [HAPROXY](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/) or for example http://crossroads.e-tunity.com/ they are light and simple to use.

I'd like to add also this: [RabbitMQ Client connect to several hosts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23010908/rabbitmq-client-connect-to-several-hosts)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. HAPPROXY seems a good option. I was wondering if using Python clients with Pika you could do something similar than when you are using Java clients:                           > ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
> Address[] addresses = {new Address("url_1", 12345), new
> Address("url_2", 12346)};
> factory.newConnection(addresses);

Comment: No, but be careful, the Java API connect the client only to ONE broker a time and not two together!
I'd like to add this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508246/rabbitmq-pika-and-reconnection-strategy I think could help you, if you want hanle an fail-over situation